# Amazon EC2 上で MySQL 8.0 が起動できない

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

以下の手順でMySQLをインストールしたのですが、起動できません。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

**インストール:**

```
$ sudo mysql80-community-source MySQL 8.0 Community enabled
$ yum install  mysql-server
```

**起動:**

```
$ systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysqld.service' for details.
```

**状態の確認:**

```
[ec2-user ~]$ systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html

Oct 01 18:44:54 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Oct 01 18:45:22 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
Oct 05 22:46:24 .ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Server...
Oct 05 22:46:25 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Oct 05 22:46:27 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
Oct 05 22:51:51 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Server...
Oct 05 22:51:52 ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqld の起動時には `sudo` を付けて実行してください。

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```